# Clear Proxy credentials from firefox

Tags: proxy, firefox

I set up my first http proxy server in Non-transparent mode :) I then set it up to for auto-detection. Even better.

But my favorite browser, firefox, is storing my credentials. So I can't switch users. I have tried:

- restarting firefox
- changing the passwords for the users
- Switching networks
- Clearing saved passwords

How do I set firefox to behave like, ugh IE, and ask for my credentials when it opens?

Answer (score 0):

You probably might want to clear "Active Logins".

There's also a setting that allows you to clear select parts of remembered history on closing Firefox so that might be the corresponding option you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Put in the browser about:config and accept the risk, then set the values for:

```
signon.autologin.proxy -> false
network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-proxies -> false
network.auth.use-sspi -> false
network.proxy.share_proxy_settings -> false
```